# pip fails for every download (Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ** (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for **)

Tags: python, installation, pip

So I needed to install a package but when I tried to download it, there was an error saying me that I needed to upgrade pip, so I did (to version 19.0.1), but it didn't work, and after that, I couldn't download any package and there is always this error :

```
C:\Users\Marina bar>python -m pip install espeak
Collecting espeak
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement espeak (from 
versions: )
No matching distribution found for espeak
```

I tried downgrading pip to version 10.0.1 with `python -m pip install pip==10.0.1` but it didn't change anything and I also tried upgrading pip correctly with 
    `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python`
but it didn't work (my python is 32-bits version 3.6)

In other forums, I found some similar problems but all of them were old and didn't change anything 
Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Pip won't respond to `pip install espeak` because it can't find a distribution called `espeak`. This is not a problem with `pip` but with what you are asking it to do, which is why downgrading it and upgrading it didn't help.

If I do this:

```
pip search espeak
```

I get

```
py-espeak-ng (0.1.7)           - Python interface for eSpeak NG
speake (0.3)                   - A wrapper for espeak for python2
speake3 (0.3)                  - A wrapper for espeak for python3
pyespeak (0.2)                 - ctypes module for eSpeak
collective.js.speakjs (1.0.0)  - Text-to-Speech in JavaScript using eSpeak
voxpopuli (0.1.5.1)            - A wrapper around Espeak and Mbrola, to do simple Text-To-Speech (TTS), with the
                                 possibility to tweak the phonemic form.
pyttsx3 (2.7)                  - An OFFLINE Python Text to Speech library (TTS) which works for both python3 and
                                 python2.This library very usefull especially if you don't want any delay in the
                                 speech produced and don't want to depend only on the internet for TTS conversion. It
                                 also supports multiple TTS engines like Sapi5 , nsss , espeak .
```

but I can't tell from this list which of the modules that `pip` knows about (if any) might be the one you want.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that this thread is old but for the new viewers of this thread, here is how I solved it:

```
!sudo apt-get install espeak
```

Later, restart the Colab session and re-run your code. It will work just fine.